# Angular 2 new (RC1) router. Nested routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In beta version from the child component (let's say `'child1'`) you could tell your parent to load (navigate to) a different child component instead of current by something like that:

```
 _router.parent.navigate(['child2']);

('_router' is injected in constructor)
```

In RC1 there's no 'parent' property anymore so it seems like the you have to use `_router.navigate()` and provide the full url starting from the app root. Something like

```
/root/grandparent/parent/child2
```

Now, the question is if the child component is only aware about parent's routes but not about grandparent - how do you do this?
Would be nice to use `_router.navigate(['../child2'])` but that gives me a weird errors like `"invalid number of '../'.`

The only way to get parent's url I found so far is that:

```
_router.routeTree._root.children[0].value.stringifiedUrlSegments
```

(you can also get there from OnActivate event)

but this looks just wrong to me. It also might differ depending on the number of parents/grandparents - I haven't tried yet.

So, is there a better way to do that or relative path should work and I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Just today I have found solution (it was in router.ts file [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/src/router.ts) line:89)

````
/**
   * Navigate based on the provided array of commands and a starting point.
   * If no segment is provided, the navigation is absolute.
   *
   * ### Usage
   *
   * ```
   * router.navigate(['team', 33, 'team', '11], segment);
   * ```
   */
  navigate(commands: any[], segment?: RouteSegment): Promise<void> {
    return this._navigate(this.createUrlTree(commands, segment));
  }
````

You need to import RouteSegment and add it you your constructor

```
import { Router, RouteSegment } from '@angular/router';
...
contructor(private $_router:Router, private $_segment:RouteSegment){}
...

//If you are in for example child1 and child 1 is sibling of child2
this.$_router.navigate(['../child2'],this.$_segment);
```