# Angular2 New (RC1) Router, nested router-outlet navigation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37199272/angular-2-new-rc1-router-nested-routes) question, I am having an issue with nested routes in the Release Candidate version of Angular2's router.

Currently, I have an application set up with routes definitions as follows

- in src/client/app/app.component.ts

  ```
  @Routes([
    // some other routes up here
    { path: '/', component: HomeComponent }
    { path: '/admin', component: AdminComponent }
  ])
  ```
- in src/client/app/+admin/admin.component.ts

  ```
  @Routes([
    // some other routes up here
    { path: '/dashboard', component: DashboardComponent  },
  ])
  ```

I should note that both the AppComponent and AdminComponent use `<router-outlet>`. When you visit `/admin/dashboard` you are nested in the router-outlet of the AdminComponent, which lives in the router-outlet of the AppComponent

Because I am working in the admin section, I want there to be a permission check when any route starting with `/admin` is visited. If the user does not have the appropriate permissions, they are navigated to the home page. Currently the way I am trying to accomplish this is

- in src/client/app/+admin/admin.component.ts

  ```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (the user does not have the right permissions) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }
  ```

This navigates to the root of the application, but throws an error from the AdminComponent template, because it is trying to build a `routerLink` for another route in the AdminComponent. My hunch is that although the path is correct, I am still in the `<router-outlet>` that lives in the AdminComponent. Somehow this may be due to the new router wanting relative paths. I'm unsure how to navigate to the root of the application and load the components in the correct router outlet. I assume this is something that can be solved with `router.parent` in the old angular2 router, but since that is not available, I need another solution.

here is the error that logs in the console.

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null
      at UrlTree.Tree.pathFromRoot (segments.ts:32)
      at _findUrlSegment (link.ts:87)
      at _findStartingNode (link.ts:98)
      at Object.link (link.ts:19)
      at Router.createUrlTree (router.ts:145)
      at RouterLink._updateTargetUrlAndHref (router_link.ts:55)
      at RouterLink.Object.defineProperty.set [as routerLink] (router_link.ts:43)
      at DebugAppView._View_AdminComponent0.detectChangesInternal (AdminComponent.template.js:247)
      at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.ts:243)
      at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.ts:345)
```

*UPDATE*

Previously, `routerLink`s in the AdminComponent Template were relative paths i.e.

```
    <a [routerLink]="['dashboard']" title="Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

Changing them to absolute paths seemed to get rid of the error and navigate correctly to the root route. Now:

```
    <a [routerLink]="['/admin/dashboard']" title="Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
```

Comment: so, your UPDATE is the solution ?

Comment: Yes, router links are url based, not route based. For more, check here http://victorsavkin.com/post/145672529346/angular-router particularly the RouterLink - More on Syntax section @nadav

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that it's this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8567 you are running into.

I also don't see a route `/` configured in the code you provided in your question which is used by `this.router.navigate(['/']);`.

Comment: I have defined `'/'` as a route in the AppComponent, I just didn't include it in my example. I've update my question to reflect that. I agree with your comment in that issue because I am not generating the routes with `*ngFor`

Comment: Can you please try to move the `/` route below the `/admin` route?

Comment: making the `routerLinks` in the AdminComponent absolute paths seemed to work. See update above

Comment: I see. The `routerLink`s you used weren't included in the question. Thanks for the feedback, interesting anyway.